# Qt QScrollBar slider shadow

Tags: qt5, qscrollbar

How can I set the shadow to slider handle of a QScrollBar like this [required style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdjS1.png)?

Inherited a class from QScrollBar, configured QStyleSheet as in the picture, tried to add a GraphicsEffect, but it is added to the whole QScrollBar, but not to the Slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but you could try with the following methods and apply your `QGraphicsEffect` after getting the style from the subcontrol, or even passing the right `painter` to the method `drawComplexControl`:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#subControlRect

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawComplexControl

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html#draw

I know that you can access to the QRect for the slider, but I don't know if this can inspire you in your quest.

```
QRect handleRect = style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ScrollBar, &option, QStyle::SC_ScrollBarSlider, this);
```